# How to access GDI+ Effect Classes in C#

Tags: c#, gdi+, bitmap, effect

I try to find out, how to access the Effect-Class and it's decendants of GDI+ in C#. 
Especially, I'm interested in these:

```
* Blur
* Sharpen
* Tint
* RedEyeCorrection
* ColorMatrixEffect
* ColorLUT
* BrightnessContrast
* HueSaturationLightness
* ColorBalance
* Levels
* ColorCurve
```

Can anybody give me a hint, how to access them in C#? I even can't find them in the .net documentation. Do I have to access the gdilus.dll directory?

Ciao!

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/7cb9ce0e-1782-49b3-bc48-9549b8b0ab90/

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library on codeplex to do just this, the next version will have full legacy support for xp (with slower processing functions) for all effects, the current version only works on vista and above, you can find it at:

http://csharpgdiplus11.codeplex.com/

It comes with full source, so you can see how it's done.